# get ajax hash url on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash, onload, back-button

so say I set a hash when i do an ajax call:

example: http://example.com/#hash.html

if I load another page and click on the backbutton, how would i detect the hash and extract the url on load?
The rest I got already covered :).

If you need more code, please tell me. btw, i'm using jquery.

Comment: if i wanted a plugin i would have asked for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an event, [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange), but it's only supported in Firefox 3.6, IE8 and I assume the latest Chromes and Safaris.

For best support, detect the `hashchange` event, and if not present, use a polling function with `setInterval()`.

So you would do something like...

```
(function() { 

   var hash = window.location.hash;

   if ('onhashchange' in window) {
      window.onhashchange = hashChanged;
   } else {
      setInterval(function() {
         if (window.location.hash != hash) {
             hash = window.location.hash;
             hashChanged();
         }
      }, 500);
   }

   var hashChanged = function() {
     alert('Hash has changed!');
   };

})();
```

Comment: thank you, hashchange is perfect :D. I only target safari so it works fine :D

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options.

The most obvious one is

```
window.location.hash;
```

...which has been part of actual JavaScript for some years ([more information here](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx) or by googling "javascript location hash").

There is also a jQuery plugin called [jQuery.Url](http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-request-variables/) which has a lot of nice features for working with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   var page = window.location.hash;
   if (page == "") page = "somedefaultpage.html";
   $("#content").load(page);
});
```

If you've wired up your navigation properly the page loaded into your content element should already be there since the browser had to navigate to that #hash

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using window.location.hash to load appropriate hash content set in url while navigating back and forth.

Hope this helps someone...cheers!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#999;
        font: arial;
    }
    .content{
        width: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        border:1px solid darkorange;
        padding: 3%;color:#999;
    }
</style>


<body>
<div class="box">
<a id="hash1" href="">Add Hash1</a>
<a id="hash2" href="">Add Hash2</a>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box a").click(function(e) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  if (location.hash === '#hash1') {
    $("div.content").html('Hash one added!');
  }
  if (location.hash === '#hash2') {
    $("div.content").html('Hash two added!');
  }
  if (location.hash === '') {
    $("div.content").html('');
  }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```