# Open Colorbox on page load if linked in a certain way

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I would like to make the colorbox work on page load only when linked in a specific way, like:

```
<a href="http://noemyrenascenca.com.br/site/produtos-noemy/#colorbox">Link</a>
```

I see that this answer teaches how to trigger colorbox when loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969963

Demo here: http://noemyrenascenca.com.br/site/produtos-noemy/ (link is "Ver Coleção").

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I wasn't clear at all.

I want to link to a page and, when that page loads, it should trigger the colorbox. But it should only be triggered when linked in a special way, not always.

For example: When you click the call to action in http://noemyrenascenca.com.br/site/, it should open http://noemyrenascenca.com.br/site/produtos-noemy/ and trigger the colorobx there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get ajax hash url on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574943/get-ajax-hash-url-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

```
//change "a" for the specific link
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 //triger color box here
 $.fn.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the question wasn't clear. I edited it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect a hash on page load, and do something with it.
In your case, you would initialize the Colorbox.

Code taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574943/get-ajax-hash-url-on-page-load):

```
(function() { 

   var hash = window.location.hash;

   if ('onhashchange' in window) {
      window.onhashchange = hashChanged;
   } else {
      setInterval(function() {
         if (window.location.hash != hash) {
             hash = window.location.hash;
             hashChanged();
         }
      }, 500);
   }

   var hashChanged = function() {
     alert('Hash has changed!');
     //This is where your colorbox would go.
   };

})();
```